# Cannot install "dash" with Python version 3.6.4

Tags: python, pip, plotly-dash

We have a large clustered Data environment with no access to the internet.  I'm attempting to install Dash from our local pip repository, but it doesn't want to install on Python 3.6.4. I've tried versions 2.0.0 and 1.21.1.

When attempting to install dash 2.0.0, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Package 'dash' requires a different Python: 3.6.4 not in '>=3.6'
```

When attempting to install dash 1.21.1, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Package 'dash' requires a different Python: 3.6.4 not in '!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*,>=2.7'
```

Neither of these appear to actually state 3.6.4 is not supported, however I can't for the life of me get it to install. Is there a version of Dash specific to Python 3.6.4, or is it simply not supported? It's not an easy environment to update the Python version so this will likely not permit us to use Dash in the near future if it is simply not supported.

Comment: Can you please paste your `pip install` command?

Comment: fwiw i was not able to reproduce this problem using the `python:3.6.4` docker image (installing dash 2.0.0)

Comment: /opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-5.1.0.1/bin/pip3 install dash --trusted-host <repo_ip_address>

Comment: I was also able to successfully install it on a docker image from the same repository using Python 3.6.9 (but still no luck on 3.6.4)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to determine my problem.

I had to download about 25 dependent packages for dash and based my download purely on the version that dash told me to download.  One of the packages (importlib-metadata) was not compatible with Python 3.6.4.  Once I downgraded this package it worked fine.

I really wish pip informed you of the specific dependency it was having an issue with rather than reverting to the one you are trying to install.